# Ubuntu is not "seeing" my wireless dongle

Tags: 14.04, wireless, netgear

I am  new Linux user, i.e. I just installed Ubuntu and have no experience.  My Netgear Wireless dongle works fine in windows but is not being seen by Ubuntu.  Is this a driver issue or something else?

Comment: What is precise model of dongle you use? Wireless Netgear N300 USB adapter?

Comment: Edit your question to include the results from `lsusb` in terminal

Answer (score 0):

in the upper bar of the Ubuntu desktop you will find a icon like a piece of cake which shows the network manager.from that menu you will find a option called enable Mobile Broadband.click on it and enable it.

then go to System settings->Network settings ->Mobile broadband.from there click add a new connection.and give relevant information to create a connection.after creation you will see the connection name you created in the network manager.click it to connect to the internet.

Comment: I disconnected the ethernet, clicked on the network icon but there was no option for enabling Mobile Broadband.

Comment: type lsusb in terminal while the usb dongle is connected.that will show information related to dongle(with device name).does it show modem off or modem on?